# SQL - Update: multi renaming of repeated entries

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, sql-update

in Oracle 11 I have a table like this

```
ID  Name
--------
1   Jim
2   John
3   Jim
4   Sue
5   Marc
6   Jim
```

Now I have to modify the names to be unique; duplicates will get a suffix. So the table should look like

```
ID  Name
--------
1   Jim_1
2   John
3   Jim_2
4   Sue
5   Marc
6   Jim_3
```

To find duplicates is the easier part, but is there a routine (a snippet) to auto_rename the duplicate and count them up?

Thanks for advice (on beginner level..)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one option; see comments within code.

```
SQL> with test (id, name) as
  2    -- sample data; you don't type that as you already have it in a table
  3    (select 1, 'Jim'  from dual union all
  4     select 2, 'John' from dual union all
  5     select 3, 'Jim'  from dual union all
  6     select 4, 'Sue'  from dual union all
  7     select 5, 'Marc' from dual union all
  8     select 6, 'Jim'  from dual
  9    )
 10  -- this is what you might need
 11  select id,
 12         name || case when cnt > 1 then '_' || rn end as name
 13  from (-- count each name's appearance and find its row number
 14         select id, name,
 15          row_number() over (partition by name order by id) rn,
 16          count(*) over (partition by name) cnt
 17        from test
 18       )
 19  order by id;

        ID NAME
---------- ------------------------------
         1 Jim_1
         2 John
         3 Jim_2
         4 Sue
         5 Marc
         6 Jim_3

6 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Comment: Thanks Littlefoot, that's a fine code. It works as described; I have to check some (undefined) topics like "check if Jim_1 already exists". Have a fine day!

Comment: Me again...
The SELECT  works fine, but now I failed to use the UPDATE. For example, I have the table "NAMES" which contain this entries (like above)
`
       ID NAME
---------- ------------------------------
         1 Jim
         2 John
         3 Jim
         4 Sue
         5 Marc
         6 Jim
`
It should be easy, but at the moment I'm not able to create the update statement ..
Thanks for help again!